# JavaScript if string is in comma delimited string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string like this: `str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle";`

and I have another text to search in this string: `search = 'apple';`

How to determine using JavaScript if `apple` exist in comma delimited string?

P.S: `str` can be with or without spaces between comma and next item.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
var str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle";
var hasApple = str.indexOf('apple') != -1;
```

However, that will also match if `str` contains "apple fritters":

```
var str = "ball, apple fritters, mouse, kindle";
var hasApple = str.indexOf('apple') != -1; // true
```

There are different approaches you could do to get more specific.  One would be to split the string on commas and then iterate through all of the parts:

```
var splitString = str.split(',');
var appleFound;
for (var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
    var stringPart = splitString[i];
    if (stringPart != 'apple') continue;

    appleFound = true;
    break;
}
```

NOTE: You could simplify that code by using the built-in "some" method, but that's only available in newer browsers.  You could also use the Underscore library which provides its own "some" method that will work in any browser.

Alternatively you could use a regular expression to match "apple" specifically:

```
var appleFound = /\Wapple,/.test(',' + str + ',');
```

However, I think your real best bet is to not try and solve this yourself.  Whenever you have a problem like this that is very common your best bet is to leverage an existing library.  One example would be the Underscore String library, especially if you're already using Underscore.  If not, there are other general purpose string utility (eg. String.js) libraries out there you can use instead.

Answer (score 10):

To really test whether the exact character sequence "apple" is an item in your comma separated list (and not just a substring of the whole string), you can do (considering optional spaces before and after the value):

If [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is available:

```
var items = str.split(/\s*,\s*/);
var isContained = items.indexOf('apple') > -1;
```

If [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is available:

```
var items = str.split(/\s*,\s*/);
var isContained = items.some(function(v) { return v === 'apple'; });
```

With a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var isContained = /(^|,)\s*apple\s*($|,)/.test(str);
```

Comment: Felix, you originally come from germany, right? sorry not sof-related ;)

Comment: This is the best answer for *exact match*, but i would change the split regexp to `/\s*,\s*/`. **EDIT** - Nevermind, you did it.

Comment: Here I was thinking you where originally a Klingon from Kronos, what a disappointment

Answer (score 3):

you can turn the string in to an array and check the search string is in it.

```
var stuffArray = str.split(","); 
var SearchIndex = stuffArray.indexOf("Apple");
```

the search SearchIndex represent the position in the array.
if the SearchIndex < 0 the item is not found.

Comment: What about say "Apple Pie" being in the list?  You'll end up with a false positive...

Comment: Index of in array need an exact match, since you split on the comma, you'll have `' Apple'` and not `'Apple'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle";
var search = "apple";
var arr = str.split(", ");
if (arr.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
   alert('yes');
} else {
   alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some great answers here arleady, but I thought I'd give an alternative using regex's.  This will be case insensitive, so will match 'Apple' or 'apple'.  Also, it will not match "Appleby's" or "apple pie", so you'll be spared false positives (or the regex can be changed to include those):

```
var str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle";
var whatToFind = "apple";
var myRegEx = new RegExp(",\\s*" + whatToFind + "\\s*,", "i");
myRegEx.test(str);
```

That was the basic regex.  Here it is inside a function and with some tests:

```
var str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle";
var str2 = "ball, apple pie, house,cat";
var str3 = "ball,Apple,house, cat";
var str4 = "ball,Appleby's, peach, dog";
strs = [str, str2, str3, str4];
var searchFor = "apple";


var matches = function (stringToSearch, whatToFind)
{
    var myRegEx = new RegExp(",\\s*" + whatToFind + "\\s*,", "i");
    return myRegEx.test(stringToSearch);
}

strs.forEach(function (st) {
    var confirm = " was ";
    if(matches(st, searchFor)==true)
        confirm = " was ";
    else
        confirm = " was not ";
    console.log( '"' + searchFor + '"' + confirm + "found in " + '"' + st + '"');
});
```

Here is the output:

> "apple" was found in "ball, apple, mouse, kindle"
>
> "apple" was not found in "ball, apple pie, house,cat"
>
> "apple" was found in "ball,Apple,house, cat"
>
> "apple" was not found in "ball,Appleby's, peach, dog"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this the very easy, yet error prone way of checking the index of the string `apple` in your comma separated list:

```
var str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle"
var index = str.indexOf('apple')
alert(index)
```

Checking the result is `>-1` tells you that the `str` contains the string `apple`. However, this will give you false positives where for example `str` is:

```
var str = "ball, crab apple, mouse, kindle"
```

That will still give you an index for `apple` that is `>-1` - probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

please note, for this code, you need jquery library

```
str = "ball, apple, mouse, kindle";
str_arr = str.split(',');
for (i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) { 
   if($.trim(str_arr[i]) === "apple"){
     alert('yiha i found an apple here. here it is: ' + str_arr[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Note this needs jquery, and you should use `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using regular expressions

```
//some test csv
var t = '1,2,3,4,32,apple,apple struddle,applestruddle,41,42,43';
```

now create a regular expression 'reg' here .. it can be done hardcoded like

```
var reg =  /(^|,\s{0,1})\bapple struddle\b(,|$)/;
```

or programmatically like

```
var check_value = "apple";
var reg = new RegExp("(^|,\\s{0,1})\\b" + check_value + "\\b(,|$)","g");
```

and you can simply call

```
if(reg.test(t)){
  console.log("apple .. no struddle!!");
}
```

Just a note on the reg exp .. I put in a \s{0,1} after the comma just to cater for a ", " vs a "," seperator.. obviously .. sort out your spacing requirements to suite yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've not been tested the performance, but I think using the array of separated values must be one of the short and straight solutions. So I suggest to get an array of values and check with inArray command like below:

```
var str = "ball,apple,mouse,kindle";
var search = 'apple';

var strArray = str.split(',');
if ($.inArray(search, strArray) !== -1) {
  alert('hurrah :)');
} 
else {
  alert('nothing!');
};
```